# Logo not displaying on Multiple Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have page that displays multiple Google Maps on one page. On the maps I have my logo in the top left. I have noticed it only displays on the first map. I have an idea why but I am not sure what I need to add for it to display on the other. It inherits all the other map controls so I not sure why it doesn't do this for the logo on both maps.

Here is a link to the page

[EXAMPLE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/wxaqiV2.php)

Here is the link to the code for the map

[CODE](http://www.mesquiteweather.net/gmap/aqiLocal.js)

Any suggestions?

-Thanks

Comment: You should post the applicable code as part of your question (not just put a link to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you are only adding it to "map":

```
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(logoControlDiv);
```

if you want it on map1, you need to add it to there as well:

```
map1.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(logoControlDiv);
```

(you might need to make another copy for map1)